# Cocoa Bindings - why do I get these characters?

Tags: cocoa, core-data, cocoa-bindings

I am trying to learn Cocoa Bindings, and have a simple app with Title, First and Last Name.

Here is a screenshot of the result when I run the app:

[image]

I don't understand why I'm getting the null strings in the first and last names.

Everything is built using bindings - there is no code.

The bindings look like this:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated... Thanks!

EDIT - here is the attribute values for firstname:

[image]

Here is the code for the managed object subclass...

```
@interface TestEntity : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * title;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * firstname;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * lastname;

@end


@implementation TestEntity

@dynamic title;
@dynamic firstname;
@dynamic lastname;

- (void) awakeFromInsert
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);

    NSString * baseValue = @" ";
    [self setValue: baseValue  forKey: @"firstname"];

} // awakeFromInsert
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You bound a control that shows only a single value to "arrangedObjects.yourKey". This provides a collection. If you printed the same thing in the debugger console using `po someCollection`, you'd see the same format.

You want "selection.yourKey". Here "selection" means "whatever object is selected in the array controller" and the rest of the keypath is rooted at that object.

You're probably used to using "arrangedObjects" with a table view, where a column (essentially an array of vertically-stacked fields wants a sorted collection. This is fine for your left-hand table (the "master" view) but your right-hand controls (the "detail" view(s)) depend on its selection.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Joshua, I tried that - and you're right- the null values are not there, but the items (first and last names) are not bound properly to the entity. So that when Title is 1, and I enter a name, when I enter Title 2, the name fields remain...

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying. Why should the name fields change when only the title field is edited? This takes extra code if the name fields depend on the title, which you didn't say. If you want a *new* item, click the add button (should select the newly-added item) and edit *its* title/firstname/lastname.

Comment: The entity attributes are title, first and last name. So when I press the +, I would expect that the text fields are cleared..

Comment: I bind the array controller with file owner > managedobjectcontext. Is this what you mean?

Comment: I'm getting asked to move this to chat. Is there anyway you could update your answer with a screenshot of what I should look for?

Comment: You can ignore the chat thing. :-) You may need to create an NSManagedObject subclass for your entity and implement -awakeFromInsert to set the names to @"" (an empty string). How to do this is a separate Google search and question, so post it as such.

Comment: Hmm. did that, also no joy.. what a bummer... I'll get there though, and I appreciate your help. (I've updated the question with the MSManagedObject subclass).

Comment: You nailed it. I re-read your posts and rebuilt the test project and it worked. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

In your model, first and last names can be null and do not have default values. Uncheck the `can be null` checkbox for each attribute.

Comment: Thanks Fabrice.. I've modified the question to show the attribute values for "firstname". Where do I set "can be null"? Thanks David

Comment: Awww. Optional checkbox. Uncheck it. You'll get an empty string instead of null.